# How to hide 'Attach Files' option in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am creating lists in WSS 3.0 and I can hide most of the columns by default, like "Title" e.t.c, but I need to hide the 'Attach File' option, and I cannot find the way to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the list settings page and choose advanced settings. You can disable attachments there.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to create a custom Edit Form for your list(s) that doesn't contain the file attachment option.  It will replace the metadata edit form that users see when they upload or edit metadata properties for list items in the given list(s).

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-HA010119111.aspx) is a nice tutorial on how to create and deploy a basic edit form replacement.